# Merge of more than 2 python pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have some data frames like this

```
num  a    --  num  b    --  num  c    --   num  d
101  0        101  1        102  0         101  1
102  1        103  1        103  0         102  0
103  0        104  0        104  1         103  1
104  0        105  0        105  1         104  1
105  1        107  1        106  1         106  0
106  1        108  1        107  1         107  0
```

I have them in an array called frames.
I want to do something like **pd.concat(frames)** and have as a result

```
num   a   b   c   d
101   0   1  Nan  1
102   1  Nan  0   0
103   0   1   0   1
104   0   0   1   1
105   1   0   1  Nan
106   1  Nan  1   0
107  Nan  1   1   0
108  Nan  1  Nan Nan
```

but I think I should use **pd.merge** to set **num** as the join on column. Using **merge** I think I can only merge 2 data frames, should I use it in a loop to merge all my data frames? or can I do this with concat or is there another (and better) way?

Comment: I'm not sure about better way, `concat` will only work if the index is set to `num` before hand, otherwise this would work: `df1.merge(df2, how='outer').merge(df3, how='outer').merge(df4, how='outer')` but it's a bit of a mouthful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
dfs = []

data = """\
num  a
101  0
102  1
103  0
104  0
105  1
106  1
"""
dfs.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True))

data = """\
num  b
101  1
103  1
104  0
105  0
107  1
108  1
"""
dfs.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True))

data = """\
num  c
102  0
103  0
104  1
105  1
106  1
107  1
"""
dfs.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True))

data = """\
num  d
101  1
102  0
103  1
104  1
106  0
107  0
"""
dfs.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True))
```

let's set `num` as index:

```
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs[i].set_index('num', inplace=True)


df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

yields:

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]:
       a    b    c    d
num
101  0.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
102  1.0  NaN  0.0  0.0
103  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
104  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
105  1.0  0.0  1.0  NaN
106  1.0  NaN  1.0  0.0
107  NaN  1.0  1.0  0.0
108  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

**OLD answer:**

try pd.concat(..., **axis=1**):

```
pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

it'll concatenate your frames horizontally by **index**, so you may want to set appropriate index beforehand

Comment: set_index was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `pd.concat`, you can also use `pd.merge`.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
a = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        "num,a\n101,0\n102,1\n103,0\n104,0\n105,1\n106,1\n"
    ),
    header = 0
)

b = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        "num,b\n101,1\n103,1\n104,0\n105,0\n107,1\n108,1\n"
    ),
    header = 0
)

c = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        "num,c\n102,0\n103,0\n104,1\n105,1\n106,1\n107,1\n"
    ),
    header = 0
)

d = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        "num,d\n101,1\n102,0\n103,1\n104,1\n106,0\n107,0\n"
    ),
    header = 0
)

mylist = [a, b, c, d]

for i in range(4):
    if i == 0:
        result = mylist[i]
    else:
        result = pd.merge(
            result,
            mylist[i],
            how = 'outer',
            on = 'num'
        )
```

And then you will get the result.

```
In [14]: result
Out[14]: 

   num    a    b    c    d
0  101  0.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
1  102  1.0  NaN  0.0  0.0
2  103  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
3  104  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
4  105  1.0  0.0  1.0  NaN
5  106  1.0  NaN  1.0  0.0
6  107  NaN  1.0  1.0  0.0
7  108  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```